# How do I CI deploy my Angular 2 app to Azure?

Tags: angular, githooks, azure-web-app-service

I currently have an Angular 2 application in a GitHub repo. I would like to deploy it as a webapp on Azure, preferably automatically, on every commit, using Git hooks. How do I do this?

Comment: This is far too broad to address on SO, but I would recommend using a CI service (e.g. Travis, which is free for open source projects and already has GitHub integrations) to run your code's tests, then (if it passes) build it and [deploy it to Azure](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/azure-web-apps/), rather than trying to do it directly in GitHub. This reduces the risk of deploying broken code. See e.g. [my project](https://github.com/textbook/known-for-web) which deploys to Cloud Foundry from Travis.

Answer (score 0):

**The scenario is supported via Azure App Services, An App Service App can host the Angular App for you** and has a feature to allow you to connect it to GitHub and trigger Continuous Deployment.

Once you commit to GitHub the App Service picks up on the GitHub commit on the branch and automatically triggers a deployment for you. **No extra configuration required, it just the matter of selecting your GitHub Account, Repo and the Branch to setup the deployment.**

Check this blog for more details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-continuous-deployment

Apart from GitHub, App Services also supports, VSTS, BitBucket, OneDrive, Dropbox, LocalGit and External Repository support.